# How to wait for a closure completion before returning a value

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, closures

How to wait to return a value after a closure completion.

Example:

```
func testmethod() -> String {
   var abc = ""
   /* some asynchronous service call block that sets abc to some other value */ {
      abc = "xyz"
   }
   return abc 
}
```

Now I want the method to return only after `xyz` value has been set for variable and not empty string.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

this is absolutely not possible, because it is just not how asynchronous tasks are working.

what you could do is something like this:

```
func testmethod(callback: (abc: String) -> Void) {
   asyncTask() {
     callback(abc: "xyz")
   }
}
```

Have a nice day.

EDIT (for newer Swift Versions):

```
func testMethod(callback: @escaping (_ parameter: String) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { // representative for any async task
        callback("Test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it is possible.

Answer (score 12):

**It is possible** *(However make sure this is what you really want.)*.

You have to use something that will block a thread until a resource is available, like **semaphores**.

```
var foo: String {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    var string = ""

    getSomethingAsynchronously { something in
        string = something
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    semaphore.wait()
    return string
}
```

> **Bare in mind** that the thread you are working on will be blocked until the `getSomethingAsynchronously` is done.

Comment: @vadian Sure you should know what and why you are doing it, but I don't agree it is a bad suggestion. Since the OP wants to know "how" without more specific conditions and accepted answer is saying it is not possible, this is perfectly legit.

Comment: Almost all people who *want to wait* have no clue or don't understand how to handle asynchronous data processing. 

Comment: @vadian do you have any numbers for `Almost all`? It's quite legit question, and I actually found this thread because of specific requirement of `XCTestObservation` function `testBundleDidFinish`, which needs to block thread until you are done. I agree it's easy to make mistake here, but don't assume that nobody will need this ;)

Comment: Waiting on an asynchronous callback with Grand Central Dispatch is considered a performance anti-pattern because it creates useless threads and is subject to priority inversion. As of Xcode 10 the Static Analyzer will highlight this as a potential “issue” (except within unit tests).

Answer (score 2):

Since Swift 5.5 the recommended way is `async/await`. If the API doesn't provide an `async` version you can create your own with a `Continuation`

```
func testMethod() async -> String {
    return await withCheckedContinuation({ continuation in
        someAsynchronousServiceCallBlock() { result in
            continuation.resume(returning: result)
        }
    })
}
```

You have to call the mathod in an asynchronous context for example in a `Task`

```
Task {
    let result = await testMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to wait for the closure function to populate the data and then return the variable. Although, it is suggested to avoid using semaphore to do that, I think that is the only way.

```
func foo() -> String {
    var str = ""
    let semaphore = DispathSemaphore(value: 1)  //1 if you are waiting for one closure function to signal the semaphore to continue the main thread execution

    getAsync() {
        //populate the variable
        str = "bar"
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    semaphore.wait()
    return str
}
```